# Do properties of exponents apply only to positive real numbers?

Tags: precalculus

A common rule given in textbooks is:

> If $a$, $b$, and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$.

Suppose I write:

> $(-9)^{1/2}=(-9)^{2/4}=((-9)^2)^{1/4}=(81)^{1/4}=3$.

But this contradicts the fact that

> $(-9)^{1/2}=\sqrt{-9}=3i$.

What did I do wrong?

I don't see a problem with changing $(-9)^{1/2}$ into $(-9)^{2/4}$. Is the issue
with going from $(-9)^{2/4}=((-9)^2)^{1/4}$, and if so, does that mean the rule given above only applies to positive bases? Are the textbooks wrong?

Comment: The statement "If $a$, $b$, and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$" is wrong.  Consider, for example, $x=0, a=-1$.  But your question is about math, and not about math education.  I've voted to close it for this reason.

Comment: There is an interesting teaching question in here, however, which is how we should address this issue in our courses.

Comment: I thought the claim that this is the usual statement of the property must be wrong. But I just looked at OpenStax's College Algebra book, and it is sadly written this way. https://openstax.org/books/college-algebra/pages/1-2-exponents-and-scientific-notation

Comment: Dang. It's the same in their beginning algebra text: https://openstax.org/books/elementary-algebra-2e/pages/6-2-use-multiplication-properties-of-exponents

Comment: What textbook were you using when you noticed this, Chad? A variation of Chad's question that might satisfy your concern, @JRN, might be to ask why the textbooks get it wrong and our thoughts on the best way to deal with that. This is an intriguing question to me. And the asking of it here will make me remember to emphasize this issue with my students when we review the properties of exponents.

Comment: @SueVanHattum Redoing this comment since I couldn't edit it: The openstax texts seem to be ok, limiting themselves to when the exponents are integers.

Comment: It's in a gray box labeled The Power Rule of Exponents, and begins "For any real number a..." It's not surprising that their examples are correct. But the OP used a property he read in a textbook, and that property was stated incorrectly. Another related question: What would be the simplest way to state this property correctly?

Comment: Chad, please change the title of this question to make it a math education question, rather than a math question. I've given you lots of options, please word it whatever way is most useful to you.

Comment: I looked at the two links provided in these comments.  openstax college algebra ... it says the exponents are "natural numbers".  openstax beginning algebra ...  it says the exponents are "counting numbers".  If you find a textbook with this rule where $a,b,x$ are real numbers, then **reject that textbook**.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, it says the base, a, is a real number. So it could be negative, but then we have the problem this post is about.

Comment: @SueVanHattum 1. The material that you cite (**A**: "For any real number a and positive integers m and n, the power rule of exponents states that $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$") is correct. $\tag*{}$ 2. Here are two related theorems: (**B**) as long as $a$ is a nonzero complex number, the exponents are allowed to be any integers; (**C**) if we restrict the base to positive reals, then the exponents can just be any reals.

Comment: Dang. I am so sorry. It said integers for the powers. Duh. Well, now I'm fine with this being closed. But I do wonder which textbook the OP was looking at.

Comment: @SueVanHattum "*What would be the simplest way to state this property correctly?*" I reckon that Option **A** is the most commonly encountered (especially at elementary levels), as it is the easiest to teach. But **B** in conjunction with **C** are the useful forms; though I guess they seldom get a chance to be presented? $\quad$ Typo above: I meant: "if we restrict the base to a positive real,"

Comment: @Chad: Please take a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2085631/21820), and remember especially the advice there: *You must know exactly what the objects are before you can apply any operations to them, not to say claim any properties about the resulting values.*

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the theorem is wrong. There are several similar looking theorems where $a,b$ are integers or where $x>0$. You should carefully check the text to make sure that you didn't miss some qualifiers. (This would probably be an easy thing for authors to miss in a first edition too, so who knows.)

The root of the problem comes from the fact that, if you view $(-9)^{1/n}$ to be "the" solution to $x^n=-9$, then you don't have just one value, but $n$ of them, i.e., $(-9)^{1/2}$ could be $3i$ or maybe $-3i$. Further, $81^{1/4}$ could be $3$, $-3$, $3i$, or $-3i$ since all of these have the correct fourth power. (Things get even messier if you want to think about things like $(-9)^{\sqrt{2}}$.) Most of the time, though, we want just one answer. Then you pick out a "principal branch" which chooses just one of these as the answer. Unfortunately, choices of principal branch may not be compatible when you bounce around between denominators. That's why the answer $3i$ shows up in the list for $81^{1/4}$. It's *a* 4th root of 81, just not the principal one.

As for teaching this topic, I feel like you need to say the right thing, but I can really see the point of not getting bogged down with the qualifiers that much.